# Localization Using jQuery

Tags: jquery, localization

I'm developing a chat application, and I want to have the application localized according to the particular language in that country. Does jQuery support this, or do I need to use something else for localization?

Comment: jQuery does not support everything! :)

Comment: It does now: https://github.com/coderifous/jquery-localize

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Asp.Net, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086801/how-to-handle-localization-in-javascript-files) might interest you.

Answer (score 2):

Well I had this localization problem to solve too. I did it without JQuery (like Arnis said Jquery doesn't solve anything).

I created XML files that hold the lang dictionary for my data. I keep these lang files in the memory and based on whichever language is set, I fetch the data using XPath functions.

It's fast, efficient, logical and works well.

Answer (score 0):

And here is another one I came up with using .net global resource files as well, but it is probably a bad idea if you have a lot of localized strings because it loads up synchronously. You'd definitely want to test this for your application, but it worked well for my situation. And of course, I don't know if you're using .net or not.

[Localize javascript messages and validation text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987594/localize-javascript-messages-and-validation-text)

Answer (score 0):

Different JavaScript libraries have different goals. jQuery doesn't support localization out of the box. Instead, I'd recommend you to take a look at internationalization functions provided by Dojo Toolkit. It supports i18n with [translation bundles](http://o.dojotoolkit.org/book/dojo-book-0-9/part-3-programmatic-dijit-and-dojo/i18n/resource-bundling) plus automatic [number, currency and date formatting](http://o.dojotoolkit.org/book/dojo-book-0-9/part-3-programmatic-dijit-and-dojo/i18n/number-and-currency-formatting) for the whole world thanks to Unicode Common Locale Data Repository.

Comment: Corrected links after Dojo moved old articles to a different sub-domain.

Comment: Now, one year later, the links are broken again.

Answer (score 0):

There's the globalize library: https://github.com/jquery/globalize

Seems pretty active and preferred by some.

Answer (score 0):

the updated doc link of dojo about localization:
http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/i18n/

Comment: 1.Welcome to Stack Overflow. We use a question and answer format here, not a threaded conversation format, which means that until you get full access to the comment system at 50 rep you can't reply to other users except on your own posts. Using an "answer" for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I have developed Jquery based Resource location plugin this can be used in any Web Application. This is very easy to use and very light weight just 3KB. You can download plugin from Github or Install via Nuget.

Refer to this link - http://www.pritambaldota.com/index.php/jquery-based-resource-localization/