# ASP.NET MVC unobtrusive jquery localization

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, localization, unobtrusive-validation

How can I localize localize error messages without specifying them on `DataAnnotations` for models? E.g. in message "The field XX is required", I want to translate only "The field --is required" part with **jQuery globalization**, I'm not using `[Required(ErrorMessageResourceName="----")]` attributes.

Is it possible to achieve this? Any code samples, tutorial links will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following approach:

```
[Display(Name = "FirstName", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources))] 
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "ErrorRequired")]
public string FirstName {get;set;}
```

Then in your Resource file you add key:

```
FirstName and translate e.g. with "first name"
ErrorRequired --> "{0} field is required"
```

This approach you can then apply to all your properties.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the answer for jquery based resource location which I have developed. Very useful plugin. Please see the answer posted here https://stackoverflow.com/a/30610862/1239344